# How to show proof of publication?

Tags: publications, research-process, research-undergraduate

I have just got my first paper accepted to a reputed IEEE (say X for generality) conference. Now, one of the authors have registered for the conference as a student member of X. I have applied for student membership, but probably won't receive the member card before registration deadline. In that case, I have been informed that only the author attending the conference would be getting the certificate. 
So I have the following question:

1) Do I need the certificate to proof that I have this publication in future ? (My dept has procedure of submitting copies of all certificates that you earn during the semester, and my co-author would definitely be submitting his there.)

2) Is it worth to register without availing student discount so that I may get the certificate ?

Comment: Interesting, I never heard of someone being asked for a proof of publication. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You don't get a "certificate" for publishing something. The fact that it is available online at the journal's website (which can take a while, depending on their publishing speeds) and has a doi (which you should receive soon after acceptance), is sufficient proof.
2. Most societies don't have a membership card either. They might send you a welcome letter, which you could use as proof of membership.

Most places accept different forms of proof of claim when a formal one doesn't exist. In your cases, the following should be just as valid:

1. An email from the editor, accepting your paper for publication (you should have this)
2. An email from the society, thanking you for your interest and membership
3. A screenshot of your member page, showing validity
4. A screenshot of the web copy of your paper (some journals throw a rough version on the web which serves till the final version is typeset).

Comment: 5. Complete bibliographic information, which anyone can use to google and download the paper themselves.

Comment: @user8581 The email from editor addresses the first author. Does that make a difference ?

Comment: @krammer It doesn't make a difference, as long as the email states the list of authors and your name is in it. For any publication, there is a "corresponding author" handling the communication with the publisher. While there is some uncertainty on how being corresponding author relates to one's contribution (see also http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/does-corresponding-author-carry-an-implied-meaning ), the paper is of course attributed to all authors.

Comment: @silvado the email just have the names of the first author. Though the email was sent to all the co-authors

Comment: For what it's worth, the IEEE does issue membership cards.

Comment: @krammer In the decision emails from IEEE conferences that I typically get, there's a section entitled "Submission information" towards the end of the email with the complete data. Don't you have anything like that?

Comment: @silvado no, at the end, it has reviewer comments only

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer speaks about journal, I just wanted to clarify for conference. 
The proceedings are prepared by the Programme Committee and submitted to IEEEXplore library. They can appear there before the conference or after the conference, depending on the arrangementes chairs made with IEEE. Once the proceedings are there, you'll be able to locate your paper and print a screenshot and/or the paper in case you need to proof the publication.
The e-mail from the PC you received should also serve as a proof of publication, as long as it mentions the authors of the papers.