# Corresponding author

Tags: publications, authorship

I am an undergraduate student in the field of information technology. Recently I worked on an academic project under a supervisor. We want to publish it. My question is: Does the person who submits the manuscript to a journal become the corresponding author of that paper? That is, if my supervisor submits the manuscript, will he become the corresponding author by default? Can’t he refer the correspondence to me?

Comment: By *corresponding*, I meant *the author to be contacted in the printed publication.* That is, my supervisor can refer the correspondence to me, though he is submitting the manuscript. Am I right?

Comment: *my supervisor can refer the correspondence to me, though he is submitting the manuscript. Am I right?* – If you mean *referring the role of corresponding author as denoted in the published manuscript,* we cannot answer this; it depends on the journal. If you mean *refer specific e-mails to you,* your supervisor can do with those e-mails whatever he wants.

Comment: As @Wrzlprmft indicated, the question is indeed related to [What is the explicit meaning of “corresponding author”?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84476/what-is-the-explicit-meaning-of-corresponding-author). In the terms of that discussion, you are not at this point **corresponding author**, and what you would like is to be listed in the published paper as **contact author**.  In my experience this is possible, _if_ the corresponding author agrees. Convince your supervisor that you should be listed as contact author and I do not see why the journal would object.