# Does being a corresponding author add extra value in SOP of PhD application?

Tags: publications, phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, statement-of-purpose

I work in a private research organization. After completing one of my projects, when I send it to my supervisor for review, he said- he doesn't want to put his name in that project and asked me to be the corresponding author. I have done similar projects earlier so this work was mostly done by me. I mean I did not have to take much help or suggestions from my supervisor. I worked myself and allocated other group members their parts.
When I submitted it, the work got published with a very minor revision in a reputed journal.

As I am applying for a Ph.D. in the USA, and in SOP, they asked me to write about prior research experience. According to me, being a corresponding author is like an achievement. But I am confused if I should write about it in the SOP or not? Is it ok if I write about it? Like this incidence has been a confidence booster for me like this?
Also, I have worked as a reviewer for a journal (reviewed 8 articles till now). Should I mention that too?

Comment: Related: [Does "corresponding author" carry an implied meaning?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10062/68109), [What is the explicit meaning of “corresponding author”?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84476/68109)

Answer (score 2):

It will probably have only a minimal impact, if any. But the SoP is not the place for it. Put it in the CV.

For more on the SoP and what to write there, see [this canonical answer about admissions in the US](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/176909/75368)