# Is there any academic advantage of being the submitting author of a paper?

Tags: paper-submission, authorship

It is well known that in most fields the order of the authors in a paper indicates the authorship, being the first one the best.

Independently of the order in a paper, does being the person that submitted the paper (*not the corresponding author*) gives any advantage, intellectual property, or academic reputation? If it does, is this field dependent, or academic culture dependent?

Comment: Do you distinguish between _submitting author_ and _corresponding author_ or is it one and the same?

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog Yes I do. Maybe often the submitting author is the corresponding author, but its not always the case. The corresponding author is the person who all correspondence about the paper should be directed to, but its no necessary that that is the person who send the paper for reviewing.

Comment: In that case, being the submitting author has only one advantage I can think of: Younger scientist and beginners are often curious about how the publication process works. If they have the opportunity to submit a paper they contributed to, this is often a useful experience.

Comment: In my field, authors are listed alphabetically; there is no special status for being the first author, last author, corresponsing author, submitting author, or author with the tallest hat, except at the Tallest Hat Contest.

Comment: The _corresponding author_ and its affiliation is relevant for the payment, see e.g. http://dx.doi.org/10.17617/1.3 where they say: "For the time being, the dominant model is that the corresponding author is responsible for picking up and settling the invoice." Additionally, the corresponding author is listed with its contact information on the paper and will be contacted by readers first (thus, the email adress should be as long-lasting as possible).

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. In which journal does the reader see who handled the correspondence with the editor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "corresponding author" carry an implied meaning?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/does-corresponding-author-carry-an-implied-meaning)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I have explicitly stated that I do not mean the corresponding author.

Comment: @Karl I asked because I have heard this being mentioned. I do not mean, of course, to the reader, but maybe there is some other advantage, perhaps inside the university, of being the author that submits the paper. This is not a random question but something I have heard people mention and confused me.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Are there any journals where the submitting author is not the corresponding author?

Comment: It is an administrative role, if you want to explicitly distinguish it. No one even know who is that person, it can be a secretary..

Comment: Yes, @Wrzlprmft, the submitting author must not be the corresponding author. Seen this several times.

Comment: Nobody, except the authors and the editor, *knows* who did the actual correspondence. This question is completely random, it depends on your personal relationship with your boss and colleagues.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft yes, this happens quite commonly around  me. Supervisors/senior colleagues submit the papers, but the first author is commonly the corresponding author in the final published version.

Comment: @Karl The question is not random, you just have answered it. The answer did not needed to be "yes".

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog: Interesting; so much that I [asked a follow-up or rather clarify-the-premise-first question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/84476/7734). (Also, you almost certainly wanted to write *need not* instead of *must not.*)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there is no academic advantage of being the submitting author of a paper.

Comment: +1 for writing a simple and correct one word answer without feeling the need to ramble on pointlessly for several paragraphs afterwards, as people sometimes do around here.

Comment: It could definitely be improved be citing some source or referencing personal experience though. Otherwise it just reads like an opinion and I'm not sure how much weight-age that deserves..

Answer (score 1):

There could be one potential advantage which is becoming part of their network (although it is possible that this also extends to the co-authors)

When I submitted a paper on editorial manager, I received a barrage of review invitations (at least four), but in another case, as a first author and not a submitting author, albeit in another journal and management system; manuscript central, I have not received any such correspondence.

Well this is all very speculative.

but what I can say definitively, is that when you are the submitting author, you manage everything that deals with the editor and journal. You manage the cover letters, you can also see little things here and there that are missing. Such as your ORCID affiliation for example. More importantly, if you are first author, you might be interested in making sure that things are done correctly! Keywords, disclosures, agreements about whether you want coloured figures or black and white figures. These are all little things that might not be communicated properly. Some might see these things as trivial and might not even ask for your input.

It also helps to become familiar with these systems. They are not a five minute job, especially when you consider the templates and other requirements that will be stated in the journal page and also restated in the online management system. If you are always co-authoring and you also happen to never submit yourself, then you miss out on some of these administrative subtleties.