# Can my PhD main supervisor claim the "corresponding author" role for papers from my thesis even if he didn't provide much support during my study?

Tags: publications, thesis, authorship

I graduated last year and is now a postdoc in another university. My current boss (who was also in my PhD supervision team, but not the main supervisor) encouraged me to publish parts of my thesis as a journal paper. I wrote the paper during working hours and my current boss gave me guidance and advice. My plan was to include others who were in the supervision team as co-authors and have my current boss as the corresponding author. However, my main supervisor was pissed off when he learnt about it. He said he should be the corresponding authors for all the papers from my thesis. Is what he said correct? Is it a must? Actually the main supervisor gave me minimal support during my study and I don't think he deserves to be the corresponding author. The funding for my study was provided by the government.

Comment: It's impossible for strangers on the internet to advise on authorship disputes.

Comment: Corresponding author is just a formality, it doesn't carry "this author has more merit".

Comment: @CapeCode I want to know the usual practice.

Comment: @Davidmh In our university it does.

Comment: @Davidmh: For some funders, fields, and similar, [it does](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10062/7734).

Comment: You got a stipend independent of who supports you as supervisor and gives you a funded project to work on?

Comment: @Karl Correct! My PhD project had nothing to do with any of the main supervisor's projects.

Comment: Rewrite the question. That is not clear. Especially who supervised the actual project which lead to this paper?

Answer (score 3):

In general, **no**.

There might be exceptions, but those should have been communicated to you in advance by your supervisor, rather than after-the-fact.

Comment: One *should* have talked about this in advance, but the answer is of course *YES*. All authors have to agree on the manuscript, including the tiny aspect of who is "corresponding author".

Comment: @Karl Indeed, any of the listed authors of a manuscript can veto against its submission for any reason. But this question is specifically about whether the PhD supervisor has a special right to being listed as corresponding author.