# How to find out the corresponding author of a paper?

Tags: funding, authorship, publishers, correspondence

I am interested to know how to find out the corresponding author of the following paper (which is just an example for the discussion here):

https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/19M1242859

It may require an access to read the full paper. Due to the copyright I prefer not to say take screen shot of the paper, but inside I find nothing indicating who the corresponding author is.

Let me elaborate more about my concern. Suppose I am the corresponding author of the paper above, and I intend to use it in a funding application. The funding provider may then check whether I am really the corresponding author. Would they contact the publisher to verify it? If so, would the publisher disclose the details? If it happens so, why don't the publisher simply list out who the corresponding author? Or the publisher would tell that in this journal we don't take the significance of the corresponding author?

Comment: There is no corresponding author.  Is there a funding agency that actually cares who the corresponding author is?  I doubt it.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I have somehow participated in some reviewing activity of a SIAM journal and I know that there is a record of corresponding author in their system but not to be seen by the public. And yes, there is funding agency does care (much) about the corresponding author (or first author). But maybe not to distract for a new discussion here.

Comment: If it's not public it's not part of the paper.

Comment: I think you have to disclose the name of the funding agency to get a useful answer.  I'm almost sure this does not actually matter.

Comment: A lot of academic papers give the  email of some author. I would try to send an email

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/does-corresponding-author-carry-an-implied-meaning

Comment: There might be some confusion here because "corresponding author" can mean two, strictly different things: 1. an author involved in the correspondence to the journal, and 2. an author designated as contact person to the public. Probably this journal only has corresponding authors in the sense of definition 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to take a look at the metadata.

My first attempt was at *CrossRef* (http://api.crossref.org/works/10.1137/19M1242859). There, in the `author` field, it seems that I. K. is the "first" author, while the two others are "additional" authors. However, "first" does not have to mean "corresponding", of course.

[image: CrossRef JSON API showing I. K. as "first author]

My second attempt was to download the metadata at *Web of Science* (full record, tab-limited file). There I found under the column `RP` (i.e. "[Reprint Address](https://images.webofknowledge.com/images/help/WOS/hs_wos_fieldtags.html)") the information:

> Kogan, IA (corresponding author), North Carolina State Univ, Dept Math, Raleigh, NC 27695 USA.

Comment: It seems rather plausible to me that the authors are ordered alphabetically, and that the Web of Science data is just wrong here.